# Variables for Javascript in snippets.cson does not work

Tags: javascript, dynamic, atom-editor, code-snippets, cson

I am trying to add dynamic snippet on Snippet conf file of Atom : "snippets.cson" .

I relied on [this thread](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues/33) And i make the following attempts :

## 1 .

```
  body:'var nowSec=${sec}';
  variables:
    sec:'new Date().getSeconds()'
```

## 2.

```
  body:'var nowSec=$sec';
  variables:
    sec:'new Date().getSeconds()'
```

## 3.

```
  body:'Array.from({length:`sec`})';
  variables:
    sec:'new Date().getSeconds()'
```

And Atom renders  `${sec}`,`$sec`, or `sec` when calling snippet ;
 which means that it does not compile it , but rather ,is does not recognize variables ?

I tried also predefined variables explained [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1883613-variables) and it does not work also .

#### - Is there something missing in `language-javascript` package configuration ?

#### - Is Ruby snippet distinguish of JS Snippet since backticks is used in JS for Strings ?